# Pandas DataFrame - What is the correct way to operate with multiple values in one cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataset which has gene names and gene ids. Basically, ids are uniquely defined, while one name can correspond to multiple ids.

I use a list to contain all ids of a gene name and the dataframe looks like:

```
|GeneName|GeneID|
|Name_1|[ID_1, ID_2, ID_5]|
|Name_2|[ID_3, ID_4]|
```

All names and ids are strings, but some ids are missing and I use `NaN` to represnt missing ones (not sure if this is a good practice either).

After saving the dataframe to a csv file and load it back, all lists containing gene ids are regarded as strings. I found a solution using:

`pd.read_csv(fpath, converters={'GeneName': pd.eval, 'GeneID': pd.eval})`

to load them as list, but I encounter

`pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'NaN' is not defined`

What is the best solution to deal with situation like this?
Thanks.

Comment: What is your desired output in the End?
Is One Hot Encoding or Binary/Hex encoding an option?

Comment: you can use empty string to represent missing ids i.e. `''`

Comment: Well, for the time being, I just want to save the dataframe to a csv file and be able to load it back. I can't find a valid solution to solve the 'NaN' error.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Hi, I tried to use `''` to replace `NaN`, but now the error becomes `ValueError: expr cannot be an empty string`.

Comment: Try with empty array i.e. `[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the problem you described in the comments you can just use empty strings to indicate missing categories.
Then use pd.eval or ast.literal_eval:

```
import ast
ast.literal_eval('["ID_1", "ID_2", "", "", "ID_5"]')

>>['ID_1', 'ID_2', '', '', 'ID_5']
```

**Important Note:**
Use different ' and " for list string and list element strings